# how to get Soap action from wsdl and generated java files. as my wsdl imports another wsdl which has @webmethod in it

Tags: web-services, soap, spring-boot, wsdl

i have a wsdl which is importing another wsdl in it. 
i wanted to call the webservice from java client code, i have configured my java class as follows

```
package test;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;


@Configuration
public class WeConfig {

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath("test");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public WeatherClient1 weatherClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        WeatherClient1 client = new WeatherClient1();
        client.setDefaultUri("*******");
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return client;
    }

}
```

I have my acessing method as follows

```
GetDataResponse response = (GetDataResponse) getWebServiceTemplate()
                .marshalSendAndReceive(
                        "*******",
                        request,
                        new SoapActionCallback("*******"));
```

My webservice would be something like

```
https://abcde.handling.com/celebrity/Confi?wsdl
```

Kindly let me know , what i have to input in setdefaultUri in configuration and soapcallbackaction. soap Ui gives me a method "GetData" for request
Thanks in advance..
 Please help ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long struggle , the answer for this query will be as follows;

DefaultUri = (Full WSDL) https://abcde.handling.com/celebrity/Confi?wsdl

there was no call back action for my request  so:

GetDataResponse response = (GetDataResponse) getWebServiceTemplate()
                .marshalSendAndReceive(
                        "Imported wsdl's URI",
                        request);